# Using STM32 to synchronize a multiple output power supply

Tags: synchronization, frequency, stm32

I want to start using STM32 MCU in order to synchronize a multiple output power supply with a single frequency.
So far I have used an analog PLL (74HC4046) for this purpose:

1. The relevant range is 200-500 kHz.
2. If the external freq. is out of range or doesn't exist the internal 400 kHz clock will distribute to all module.

First of all, is it possible? 
And if so, are there any examples?

I am using STM32L053 Discovery.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does you current solution (with the analog PLL) do exactly? What do you mean by external freq, what is the source of that. Basically you want to produce a 400 kHz clock signal with the MCU?

Comment: external freq is a 5v, 200-500Khz 50%DC that produced by my client and supply to my system.
while the ex freq is normal the MCU provide the ex freq.
but if the ex freq is lost or out of range the MCU output frequency must  change gradually as PLL does

Comment: So if I understand, you want to monitor this frequency and if anything goes wrong you want the STM32 to produce a 400 kHz clock instead?

Comment: external freq is a 5v, 200-500Khz 50%DC that produced by my client and supply to my system. while the ex freq is normal the MCU provide the ex freq. but if the ex freq is lost or out of range the MCU output frequency must change gradually as PLL does

Comment: Not only monitor also extract as output:

if freq in range=> output = input

else output = 400Khz

Comment: I think it is certainly possible. Though it would be better not to take the original signal through the MCU. Instead you could simply measure its frequency and as long as it okey, let this clock to be active. If the it is out of range you should gate this signal by the MCU and output a 400 kHz then. So basically I am speaking a clock signal switching circuit which is controlled by the MCU.  200-500Khz is one input and the 400 kHz form the controller is the other. Only one is active at a time, the other is gated. Note that the STM32 max logic level is 3.6 V so you need additonal circuit for 5 V

Comment: The reason I want to take the original signal through the MCU is in case of sudden frequency change, even if in the range (for example jumping from 200Khz to 400Khz) I want the output to change gradually like in a PLL and not jump in one step like the input.